# Can I recharge 12V batteries individually while why are attached in series?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, solar-cell, 12v, 24v

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Charging two lead-acid batteries connected in series, separately (with two solar panels)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34053/charging-two-lead-acid-batteries-connected-in-series-separately-with-two-solar)

I have 12V Solar Panels and 12V batteries. But my laptop needs 17V to recharge. I could attach 2 12V batteries in series, and I would get a 24V current. And I could use this to recharge the laptop.

But then I need to recharge the battery. So, suppose I use two different solar panels for this:
Can I attach each single 12V battery to a solar panel while they are also attached in series between them?

Thanks,
Pietro

Answer (score 0):

Series is risk especially for mismatched batteries. In order to prevent thermal runaway of a weak cell each cell must be matched within 3%.  I suggest you stick with parallel operation but ensure they are matched in model and age and consider a boost regulator that prevents undervoltage on PV panel by voltage feedback and overvoltage by voltage feedback. and let it run anywhere around 16 to 18V. THat will be fine for the DC-DC step-down ocnverters for the laptop cells and MOBO DC-DC converters. How you do it depends on your power budgets.

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid your answer went way above my head. So what you are saying is that putting batteries in series is dangerous?